# Trigger multiple pthreads by pthread_cond_broadcast

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, condition-variable

Since the examples for pthreads with `pthread_cond_broadcast` wakeup are sparse i wrote one, but are unsure if this is correctly synchronized and the way to do it:

1. do all threads share the same c and mtx variable?
2. is it necessary upon `pthread_cond_wait` return to test if some condition is actually met? in my case every call to broadcast should wake up every thread exactly once, but no-one else should do so. (do i prevent spurious wakeups?)
3. the program currently does not exit despite async cancel type. also no success with deferred cancellation tried in example code despite `pthread_cond_wait` being a cancellation point [so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15643766/4933053).

overall does it work like i expect it to.

```
 #include <pthread.h> 
    #include <iostream>
    #include <unistd.h>

    struct p_args{
        int who;
    };

    pthread_cond_t  c;      //share between compilation units
    pthread_mutex_t mtx;

    void *threadFunc(void *vargs){
        //pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS,NULL);
        struct p_args * args = (struct p_args *) vargs;

        while(true){
            //wait for trigger one loop
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
            pthread_cond_wait(&c, &mtx);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
            //should be entangled output showing concurrent execution
            std::cout << "t " << args->who << std::endl;

            /* expensive work */
        }
        delete args;
    }

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        pthread_cond_init(&c, NULL);
        pthread_mutex_init(&mtx, NULL);

        pthread_t thread_id[2];

        struct p_args *args0 = new p_args();
        struct p_args *args1 = new p_args();
        args0->who = 0;
        args1->who = 1;

        pthread_create(&thread_id[0], NULL,  threadFunc,    args0);
        pthread_create(&thread_id[1], NULL,  threadFunc,    args1);

        sleep(3);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&c);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
        sleep(3);//test if thread waits  
        pthread_cancel(thread_id[0]);
        pthread_cancel(thread_id[1]);

        pthread_join (thread_id[0], NULL);
        pthread_join (thread_id[1], NULL);
        //could perform cleanup here
        return 0;
    }

Regarding exiting deferred:
thread_id[0] exits fine and i am stuck in line `pthread_join (thread_id[1], NULL);`, it says (Exiting) but seems stuck on a lock, with debugger:  
<br>
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
<br>
```

**EDIT** final solution i came up with:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

struct p_args{
    int who;
};

pthread_cond_t  c;
pthread_mutex_t mtx;
bool doSome[2];
bool exitFlag;

void *threadFunc(void *vargs){
    struct p_args * args = (struct p_args *) vargs;

    while(true){
        //wait for trigger one loop
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        do {
            pthread_cond_wait(&c, &mtx);
            if(exitFlag) {
                std::cout << "return " << args->who << std::endl;
                delete args;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
                return NULL;
            }
        } while(doSome == false);
        doSome[args->who] = false;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
        std::cout << "t " << args->who << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pthread_cond_init(&c, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mtx, NULL);
    pthread_t thread_id[2];

    struct p_args *args0 = new p_args();
    struct p_args *args1 = new p_args();
    args0->who = 0;
    args1->who = 1;

    doSome[0] = doSome[1] = true;
    exitFlag = false;
    pthread_create(&thread_id[0], NULL,  threadFunc,    args0);
    pthread_create(&thread_id[1], NULL,  threadFunc,    args1);

    doSome[0] = doSome[1] = true;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&c);
    sleep(3);
    doSome[0] = doSome[1] = true;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&c);
    sleep(3);
    exitFlag = true;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&c);

    pthread_join (thread_id[0], NULL);
    pthread_join (thread_id[1], NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Off topic but... any particular reason you're using the `pthread` API rather than [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) -- for which there is lots of example code available.

Comment: i try to learn about pthreads and std::thread with c11 not always available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. do all threads share the same c and mtx variable?

Yes, just like any other global variable. You could print their addresses from each thread to confirm it.

> 2. is it necessary upon pthread_cond_wait return to test if some condition is actually met?

Yes, all wait interfaces are subject to spurious wakeups, and you're always responsible for checking your own predicate. See the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html) or a good book.

> 3. the program currently does not exit ...

`pthread_cancel` is uniformly horrible and should never be used. It's really hard to get right. If you want to tell your thread to exit, write a notification mechanism - build it into the existing predicate loop - and signal/broadcast to make sure all threads wake up and realize it's time to die.

> Regarding exiting deferred: thread_id[0] exits fine and i am stuck in line pthread_join (thread_id[1], NULL);, it says (Exiting) but seems stuck on a lock

One of the hard things about `pthread_cancel` is *cleanup*. If cancellation occurs while you're holding a lock, you need to have used `pthread_cleanup_push` to emulate cancel-compatible RAII semantics. Otherwise the first thread may (and in this case, did) die with the mutex still locked.

In this case the second thread is trying to exit from `pthread_const_wait` due to cancellation, but it needs to regain the lock and can't.

---

The usual form of a condition variable loop is this (and a good reference book should show something similar):

```
void *thread(void *data)
{
    struct Args *args = (struct Args *)data;

    /* this lock protects both the exit and work predicates.
     * It should probably be part of your argument struct,
     * globals are not recommended.
     * Error handling omitted for brevity,
     * but you should really check the return values.
     */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&args->mutex);

    while (!exit_predicate(args)) {
        while (!work_predicate(args)) {
            /* check the return value here too */
            pthread_cond_wait(&args->condition, &args->mutex);
        }
        /* work_predicate() is true and we have the lock */
        do_work(args);
    }

    /* unlock (explicitly) only once.
     * If you need to cope with cancellation, you do need
     * pthread_cleanup_push/pop instead.
     */
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&args->mutex);

    return data;
}
```

where your custom code can just go in `bool exit_predicate(struct Args*)`, `bool work_predicate(struct Args*)` and `void do_work(struct Args*)`. The loop structure itself rarely needs much alteration.

Comment: with your advise the above working example resulted. is this correctly done?

Comment: No need to write an infinite loop with a conditional return inside, you could just do `while(!exitFlag)`. No need to unlock and re-lock the mutex every time round the loop as well, it just thrashes it for no reason. Lock once before the `while(!exitFlag)` loop and unlock after - the wait will take care of everything else.

Comment: the threads should work concurrent but you state `* work_predicate() is true and we have the lock */`, also if `/* check the return value here too */` i need to return from within the second while, since break throws me into do work. mmh

Comment: you can always unlock/re-lock inside `do_work` if it's long-running. It's still easier to reason about than complicating the top-level thread loop.